# Remove parent theme action in child

Tags: actions, child-theme

I'm creating a child theme from Storefront.

Now I want to remove these action in child theme

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop','storefront_sorting_wrapper',9 );
```

by this function:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme','remove_action', 100 );
  function remove_action() {
    remove_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop');
  }
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For removing an action hook you should use the same action name, callback name and the priority that was used to add a action in parent theme. 
And register it on `init`

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action');
function remove_my_action() {
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop','storefront_sorting_wrapper',9 );
}
```

Read about [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

Comment: Thanks, I spent an hour looking for the correct answer, this worked.

Answer (score 8):

@Sumit is right, but if you call your function remove_action() Wordpress will throw an error. So this will work:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_actions_parent_theme');

function remove_actions_parent_theme() {
     remove_action( 'storefront_header','storefront_skip_links',0 );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice @Drik corrected. I just copied from OP :D